# how to rewrite conditions as conditions&& True

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, piecewise

I have a result comes from `Reduce`

```
a <= -2 || (1 < a < 2 && (x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a))) || a >= 2
```

it has a form that

> (a cond && x cond) || (a cond && x cond) || etc.

Since `cond && True` gives out `cond` ,so `True` is being simplified.

how to rewrite it as

```
a <= -2&&True || (1 < a < 2 && (x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a))) || a >= 2&&True
```

Comment: Does `PiecewiseExpand` help?

Comment: @mikado `a <= -2 || (-2 < a <= -1 && (x <= 1/3 (-4 + 4 a) || x >= 4 + 4 a)) || 
  a >= 2 // PiecewiseExpand` seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
Replace[
  a <= -2 || (1 < a < 2 && (x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a))) || a >= 2,
  statement : Except[_And] :> Inactive[And][statement, True],
  {1}
]
```

Note the necessity to use `Inactive[And]`, since otherwise the `True` in `And[..., True]` will disappear immediately again. Also note that `BooleanConvert` can be useful to ensure that the logical statement is always formulated as an `Or`.

Comment: thx, now only a little question. `Replace[a <= -2 || (1 < a < 2 && (x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a))) || a >= 2, statement : Except[_And] :> Defer@And[statement, True], {1}] /. (Or[a_ && b_]) :> {b, a} // Apply[Piecewise[{##}] &]` I run this code. it return `Piecewise[{{True, a <= -2}, {x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a), 1 < a < 2}, {True, a >= 2}}]` and a error. but I run `Piecewise[{{True, a <= -2}, {x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a), 1 < a < 2}, {True, a >= 2}}]` , It will give out what I want. So , how can I directly get what i want?

Answer (score 2):

Someone in QQ group(QQ: 2636051698 ) give me two answer.

```
Replace[Unevaluated@
 Unevaluated[
  a <= -2 || (1 < a < 2 && (x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a))) || a >= 2], 
statement : Except[_And] :> 
 And[statement, True], {2}] /. (Or[a_ && b_]) :> {b, a} // 
List @@ # & // Piecewise
```

or

```
Replace[Hold[
 a <= -2 || (1 < a < 2 && (x >= 1/3 (4 + 4 a))) || a >= 2], 
statement : Except[_And] :> 
 And[statement, True], {2}] /. (Or[a_ && b_]) :> {b, a} // 
Apply[Piecewise[{##}] &, #, {1}] & // ReleaseHold
```

and some references

https://github.com/wuyudi/good-books/blob/master/UnevaluatedExpressions.nb